# XDT Transform: InsertBefore - Locator Condition is ignored

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

I have a web.config file in which I need to either insert the `<configSections />` element or manipulate children of that node if it already exists.
If it already exists I don't want to insert it again (obviously, as it is only allowed to exist once).

Normally, that would not be a problem, however:

> If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child element of the  element.

[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So if I use `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` the `<configSections />` element will always be inserted after any existing child elements (and there are always some), violating the above restriction of it having to be the first child element of `<configuration />`

I attempted to make this work in the following way:

```xml
 <configSections
    xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])"
    xdt:Locator="Condition(not(.))" />
```

Which works perfect, if the `<configSections />` element doesn't already exist. However, the condition I've specified seems to be ignored.

In fact, I've tried a few conditions like:

```
Condition(not(/configuration[configSections]))
Condition(/configuration[configSections] = false())
Condition(not(/configuration/configSections))
Condition(/configuration/configSections = false())
```

Finally, out of desperation, I tried:

```
Condition(true() = false())
```

It still inserted the `<configSections />` element.

It is important to note that I'm trying to include this in a NuGet package, so I will be unable to use a custom transform ([like the one AppHarbor uses](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/07/27/custom-web-config-transforms-and-merges)).

Is there any other clever way to get my element in the right place only if it doesn't yet exist?

To test this out, use [AppHarbors config transform tester](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/). Replace the Web.config with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="initialSection" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

And Web.Debug.config with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <configSections
    xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])"
    xdt:Locator="Condition(true() = false())" />

  <configSections>
    <section name="mySection" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </configSections>

</configuration>
```

The result will show two `<configSections />` elements, the one containing "mySection" being the first, as specified in the InsertBefore Transform.
Why was the Locator Condition not taken into account?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly nodes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So after facing the same issue, I came up with a solution. It's not pretty nor elegant, but it works. (At least on my machine)

I just split the logic into 3 different statements. First, I add an empty configSections at the correct position (first). Then I insert the new config to the **last** configSections, which would be the new one if it is the only one, or a previously existing one otherwise.
Lastly I remove any empty configSections elemnt which might exist. I'm using RemoveAll for no good reason, you should probably use Remove.

The overall code looks like so:

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])" />
<configSections xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/configSections[last()])">
    <section name="initialSection" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
</configSections>
<configSections xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Condition(count(*)=0)" />
```

The question which still remains unanswered is why Locator conditions are not taken into account for InsertBefore. Or why I can't handle an empty match set for InsertBefore, because that would allowed me to do fun things such as

```
//configuration/*[position()=1 and not(local-name()='configSections')]
```

Which to be honest is a much clearer way of doing what I want to achieve.

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm, even included in a NuGet package! It's indeed a hack but it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I thought this was going to be a weird quirk that I could find no easy workaround for but this worked perfectly!

Comment: For the unintall, I just removed the section's config and the section itself, by name:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity" xdt:Transform="Remove">
  </unity>
</configuration>

Comment: I tried @Sebastiaans original solution (below) with Visual Studio 2015 and it still does not work.  So I went with @Itarmaram's answer above. `<configSections
    xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])"
    xdt:Locator="Condition(not(.))" />`

Comment: I have been using this approach for several months now and it worked great until I came across a project with an empty app.config file. 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>`

Comment: I handled an empty app.config by adding a dummy element before the @Itamaram's example and removing that element at the end.