# How to insert <configSections> as first child in app.config

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, app-config, xdt-transform, xdt

I'm currently authoring a new NuGet package, but I can't get the ***app.config.install.xdt*** file right (which is the xml file that transforms app.config to suit the installed package).

The problem is inserting a **<configSections>** section in app.config as the first child - *but only in case it is missing!*

It MUST be the first child, or the application will fail with an exception (Microsoft enforcement).

If I just use the regular **“InsertIfMissing”** transform, the insertion takes place *after* any existing children, so that seems a no-go.

What can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

I've had exactly the same problem and solved it this way:

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])" />
<configSections xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/configSections[last()])">
     do_your_stuff_with_sections_here...
</configSections>
<configSections xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Condition(count(*)=0)" />
```

The first line unconditionally creates the node as first child:

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])" />
```

The second line makes sure all your edits are done to the last configSections node, which is de correct node if it already existed…

```
<configSections xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/configSections[last()])">
```

After the transforms you do in de configSections block, you enter a command that removes all empty configSections nodes… (last line)

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Condition(count(*)=0)" />
```

Comment: Great solution.  Not sure why this isn't marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to insert  as first child in app.config

You can utilize the attribute `xdt:Transform="InsertBefore"` to insert a new  element in the  section but before the any other element, like:

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])" />
```

Certificate: [XDT Transform: InsertBefore - Locator Condition is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737022/xdt-transform-insertbefore-locator-condition-is-ignored)

And see [How to use XDT in NuGet - Examples and Facts](https://blog.nuget.org/20130920/how-to-use-nugets-xdt-feature-examples-and-facts.html) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really. The problem is that the section is inserted unconditionally. This means, if I remove the nuget package and reinstalls it, I am left with *two* <configSections>-children and not only one. There must be only one, and that one must always be the first child.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the solution as well...

```
<configSections xdt:Transform="Remove" />
<configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])">
```

Comment: You should note remove the node if you are not sure it is empty